# SonarQube UnusedPrivate constructor

Tags: java, sonarqube, static-analysis

SonarQube is throwing an error for my below code.
I have an enum that accepts String. I want users to use the `valueOf` method of my enum. Example: `MyEnum.valueOf("good")`. Hence I had to create a constructor which takes String as a parameter. But SonarQube is not letting me get away with it.
It is currently throwing me an error asking me to remove the unused private constructor. Removing the constructor is not possible as it will raise a compilation error for not having a constructor with String as parameter.

How can I make SonarQube ignore this or is there any alternative solution for my coding?

Below is my code.

```
public enum MyEnum {
    GOOD("good"), 
    BAD("bad"), 
    BETTER("better");

    private MyEnum(String value){//asks me to remove this. But I can't do that

    }
}
```

Comment: I believe it shall be just a warning for an unused code. And if its unused, why not get rid of the code ?

Comment: Yes it is an used code that's what it says. But i can't remove that as it give me compilation error for not having constructor with String.

Comment: Do you use `MyEnum.GOOD` (or `BAD` or `BETTER`) anywhere else in your program?  I've confirmed that if you evaluate any one of those enum objects, the constructor is called for all three of them.  So the code wouldn't be unused.  If SonarQube says it's unused, then this looks like a bug.

Comment: Exactly my point, either the entire code is unused or Sonar is unable to detect the usage.

Comment: I will be using MyEnum enm = MyEnum.valueOf('good"); in my code

Comment: Using `MyEnum.valueOf` should be enough to get the program to call the constructor on the three objects, so the constructor shouldn't be considered unused unless the code containing `MyEnum.valueOf` is never executed and SonarQube can figure it out.  Please note: `MyEnum.valueOf("good")` will throw an exception, because `valueOf()` only uses the identifiers.  The strings you pass to a constructor don't automatically replace the identifier.  You have to store the strings yourself, and write your own method (not `valueOf`) to retrieve the `enum` object for the string.

Comment: What is the version of SonarQube you are using ? What is the version of SonarJava installed on your SonarQube server ? and which rule is raising the issue (rulekey) ?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. In my case, the production code does not refer directly to concrete instances of `MyEnum` (test code does) but the production code does use `MyEnum.values()` to find appropriate `MyEnum` instances. The failing rule is `squid:UnusedPrivateMethod` on `SonarQube 6.7.6`, `SonarJava plugin 5.10.1` and `Java 8`.

Answer (score 5):

The `squid:UnusedPrivateMethod` raises this issue, but its [documentation](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-java/blob/master/java-checks/src/main/resources/org/sonar/l10n/java/rules/squid/S1144_java.html) mentions:

> This rule doesn't raise any issue on annotated methods.

So a simple workaround is to annotate the constructor with `@SuppressWarnings("unused")`

```java
public enum MyEnum {
    GOOD("good"), 
    BAD("bad"), 
    BETTER("better");

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private MyEnum(String value){
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the right solution, reg. the Java docs,another possibility is to mark issue as wont fix or something similar, I know its possible somewhere in SonarQ ui

Comment: It is indeed possible in the SonarQube UI. However but due to some company policy our developers (including me) don't have the required privileges to do that. This annotation is the next best thing.